# XamarinMediaManager pause/resume livestream

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, live-video

I am using **Baseflow**'s [XamarinMediaManager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager) and I can't figure out a way to resume to the "live" marker of a livestream when the player is paused.

When I pause a live streamed source, there is no way I can find to jump back to live. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.SeekTo(TimeSpan.FromHours(9999));
```

Is there a method i'm missing to jump to the live marker?

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment due to low REP but maybe try this:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play()
```

Comment: I have tried this with no luck. It starts over at the begining.

Comment: Stop and Play the source again. ...Current.Stop() / ...Current.Play()

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reassign the content of CrossMediaManager and play it, this will reassign the resource starting in its default position which in your case is live mode.

To do this you only need to implement the following code:

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(url);
```

Have a great day Chris, hope it helps!